# sql server 2012 express login error to sqlexpress

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I downloaded SQlManagementStudio_x86.exe for Windows 7 32bits. I install SQL Express 2012 correctly. It connect correctly with SqlServer Auth to remote server but I cannot connect to localhost. I tried MachineName\SQLExpress and Windows authentication but it gives me an error message saying cannot connect.
Also in the Services I only see a SQL Server VSS Writer. it does not appear SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS).
What i am missing?
Thanks